Does SpaceX plan to reuse Booster 12?
Today (10/13/24), SpaceX launched Starship for the fifth time and, for the first time, successively landed/caught a Super Heavy booster, Booster 12.
I know that the first Falcon 9 Booster recovered, B1019, was never reused and just put on display. Will SpaceX do something similar for Booster 12, or do they plan to actually fly it again?

doubtful, after all the fire damage around the engine bay are chine.  My guess is it's destined for inspection then maybe a place of honor in the parking lot, but it might also be destined for scrap.  Only a guess though, so not an answer.

The first Falcon 9 booster to land is on display outside of the SpaceX Falcon 9 factory (and former headquarters) in Hawthorne, California. The same might be true of Booster 12 based on a comment made by SpaceX commentator Dan Huot in Boca Chica a few seconds after the beginning of the boostback burn, “I’m seeing six out of six Raptors lit, hopefully I got a booster on the way back to me, I’m gonna send it to you guys in Hawthorne." Although transporting a Super Heavy to a Los Angeles suburb would be a lot more difficult than transporting a Falcon 9 booster which was designed for roads.

Given the rapid pace of development of the Superheavy booster, Starship and the Raptor engine, the availability of an updated version of the booster and the damage done to B12  (both burning around the engines and damage to one of the chines), I think it is extremely unlikely that B12 will ever fly again as Erin Anne suggests.

@Slarty Well, at some point they will need to prove that the booster is, in fact, able to refly as well. Even though its an older version, maybe it might be useful to use just to test reflight.

My guess is that they will probably test it with possibly a WDR or maybe even a static fire to see how well it functions after flight, but I don’t expect B12 to fly again.

@Starship well yes obviously, but at this stage of development there is really no point. There are many other things they need to iron out before they start working on reuse such as getting Raptor 3 running, repositioning the grid fins, incorporating the interstage into Superheavy and sorting out the problems with generating high pressure gaseous oxygen for autogenous pressurization free from contamination with water and carbon dioxide so that most of the internal tank filter systems can be removed. We don't know for sure but if B12 flies another sub-orbital  test flight I will eat my hat.

Elon tweeted that the outer engine bells were warped from the heat. He wrote:

Just inspected the Starship booster, which the arms have now placed back in its launch mount. Looks great!


A few outer engine nozzles are warped from heating & some other minor issues, but these are easily addressed.


Starship is designed to achieve reflight of its rocket booster ultimately within an hour after liftoff. The booster returns within ~5 minutes, so the remaining time is reloading propellant and placing a ship on top of the booster.

I expect they will not spend time fixing Raptor 2 engine issues, since Raptor 3 a really optimized design is coming for the V2 Booster and Ships.
But it seems if there was engine damage they may not refly. It is not clear if you swapped out all the engines and reflew the booster if that was a real test of reusability.

"It is not clear if you swapped out all the engines and reflew the booster if that was a real test of reusability." From an engineering standpoint, if you're saving money (and/or time, which you can also reduce to money) over just building another vehicle fresh you're winning, even if you could do better.  From a philosophical standpoint, if you pull all the engines into a reuse flow and reuse them later, even swapping out the engines is probably fine.

At the moment, at least, the Starship program is still in a somewhat position. They really want to get to full and rapid reusability as fast as possible, and they do need to test and demonstrate reflying vehicles for that, but at the same time, reusing a vehicle doesn't make sense because they are still iterating so much. Every vehicle is essentially obsolete as soon as it rolls out of the megabay. So, why refly an obsolete vehicle when you could instead verify the changes you made on a new one? Remember, SpaceX is still limited to 5 launches per year under the current PEA.

"It is not clear if you swapped out all the engines and reflew the booster if that was a real test of reusability."  Spaceship of Theseus?
